# C: For Loop: Why does a loop-continuation condition of "z" work the same as "z > 0"with a decrement of z--?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Full disclosure: I think I have answered my own question by formalising all of this. Please can you check my logic?

Using the following terminology:
for (initialise control variable; loop-continuation condition [Boolean expression]; de/increment)

I have written a loop which prints out a Mario style pyramid:

```
    Welcome to Super Mega Mario! 
    Height: 5
        #  #
       ##  ##
      ###  ###
     ####  ####
    #####  #####
```

Within the code, I use two different loop-continuation conditions:

```
for (int z = i + 1; z > 0 ; z--)
for (int z = i + 1; z ; z--)
```

I am unsure why the second example works, below is my attempt to explain.

Why I think both of these work:

First example (z > 0):

To print the final line #####  #####, the for function prints "#" 5 times. First, because z == 5, so Bool is true, so print "#". Then z == 4, Bool is true, so print "#". This continues
until z == 0, so the Bool is FALSE, so break.

Second example (z):

All non-zero values are true, z is 5,4,3,2,1. When z is 0 (FALSE), break.

I am learning, I want to develop excellent style and design, if you can explain which example is better designed, please let me know! Also, if you can recommend edits for my style, then please HMU too. [Source code @ end].

```
    int main(void)
    {
        int n;//Declare variables outside of loops to allow "while" function to use it.
        printf("Welcome to Super Mega Mario! \n");
        do
        {
            n = get_int("Height: "); //prompt user for height of pyramid.
        }
        while (n < 1 || n > 8);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//How many rows will be created
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) //column
            {
                for (int x = n - i - 1; x; x--) //for(initialise control variable; loop continuation condition [boolean expression]; increment)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                for (int y = i + 1; y; y--) //If the loop continuation condition is y, then it's TRUE. So the function will run. Then it decreases this value by 1, so it's now 0 or FALSE so the function breaks.
                {
                    printf("#");
                }
                printf("  ");
                for (int z = i + 1; z > 0 ; z--) //In theory "z>0" works the same as z on its own.
                {
                    printf("#");
                }
                break;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In a condition, `if (z)`  is the same as `if (z != 0)`. Also works in for-loop conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z` inside an expression is equivalent to `z != 0`. All non-zero values (positive or negative) are to be regarded as a boolean true when placed inside an expression. Similarly, given a pointer `int* p;` then `if(p)` is equivalent to `if(p != NULL)`.

---

> if you can explain which example is better designed, please let me know!

- Style is subjective, though generally it is regarded as better style to be explicit, since that gives self-documenting code and rules out typos. If I type `if(p != NULL)` then there can be no misunderstanding what I meant the code to do. If I however type `if(p)`, that could either be what I meant, or it could potentially be a bug when I actually meant to de-reference the pointer `if(*p)`.
- On the topic of style, it is often best to keep `for` loops as simple as possible. That means avoid needless complex expressions in the 3 `for` clauses and do up-counting loops whenever possible. The idiomatic form of a `for` loop is:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  ```

  and we should try to strive to be as close to that as possible. For example in case of  `for (int z = i + 1; z > 0 ; z--)` it doesn't matter which order you iterate in, so the down-counting is just obfuscation. There is no reason why this shouldn't be written as `for(int z=0; z<i; z++)`.
- Also style: no matter which brace placement style you use, it is convention to always write the `while` in `do while` at the same line as the `}`. That is: `} while (n < 1 || n > 8);`
- Bug here: `break;` prevents the `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)` loop from running more than once.

Comment: Amazing, you answered my question with such clarity. 
After doing some more problems, I came back to this and what you have said has really sunk in. Thanks for the help Lundin! 

People like you really make my day :)